# Auto import in Visual Studio Code only offering absolute path with Lerna subpackages in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, auto-import

For some reason, very recently my Visual Studio Code changed and started only offering absolute imports from the sub-package level with my Lerna packages, for example:

[image]

As you can see, the auto import is suggesting the `@package/server/src/database` path to the file when it should just be `../database` as the file being edited is within the same package and is just one folder below the file containing the database variable I'm trying to use.

Is this a bug or configuration issue?

I've set my `Import Module Specifier`setting for TypeScript in Visual Studio Code to all three options (auto, relative, and absolute) and none of them seem to make any difference.

Comment: I'll play with this if you set up a repository that I can clone to reproduce the problem.  (I don't want to spend the time to try to set up a project like yours by myself only to potentially fail to reproduce the problem.)

Comment: Fwiw, at least one user has `importModuleSpecifier` set to `relative` in workplace and user files and it still imports with a full pat -- edit: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51443713/1028230) suggested TS version -- there, a different version and issue -- could cause weirdness. Changing from TS 2.3.2 to 3.4.5 resolved this issue for me. /shrug

Answer (score 618, accepted):

In Visual Studio Code, menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* → *User Settings*,

```
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"
```

It works fine for me. It imports

```
import { RegistrationComponent } from '../../abc-modules/registration/registration.component';
```

in place of

```
import { RegistrationComponent } from 'app/abc-modules/registration/registration.component';
```

Comment: Thank you! When it's set to auto, it seems to change between using relative and absolute.

Comment: I will pointout something: It is much better to have absolute path but starting from source dir (src/) like "import .. from "my-module/bla/bla/ClassName.js" because that approach will let You move packages and classes without changing imports. So You should avoid relative paths.

Comment: John Tribe's advice is legit with Vanilla JS. However I use TypeScript with "src" folder for TS and "dist" folder for transplied JS, so absolute path causes runtime error.

Comment: amazing solution. @hirikarate, do your self a favor, stop using abs paths. the ecosystem does not fully supports it (including the IDEs). I spent 6 months to make it work. total waste of time

Comment: `JavaScript › Preferences: Import Module Specifier
Preferred path style for auto imports.` --> `relative` (Also, for jest testing, absolute paths break the test suite @JohnTribe.)

Comment: If it's not working: Note that you need to change the Typescript > Preference, not Javascript > Preference

Comment: Did anyone tell you if this is more beautiful?

Comment: There is also "project-relative" now, which makes it only prefer the relative import from within the same project. Useful for us with an NX monorepo setup, using tsconfig paths. Just using "relative" made vscode suggest relative imports instead of our configured paths.

Answer (score 89):

In Visual Studio Code, menu File → Preferences → Settings → User Settings

search by importModuleSpecifier

[image]

Comment: It's works for me. Remember this tip works only typescript. You need the same steps to works do .js files

Comment: Oh it's doing shortest for default! I could not figure out why some imports were /app and some were ../ That's a good brainteaser. I failed.

Comment: + better to use "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "project-relative"

Answer (score 11):

My problem was that I had the `baseUrl` option set in my `tsconfig.json` file.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".", // remove
  },
}
```

After removing the option; VSCode immediately started importing via the relative path. The benefit of this method is that you can keep the VSCode option `importModuleSpecifier` set to `shortest` and relative path importing will still work.

Comment: This was the most acceptable solution in my case as I wanted to keep using my webpack aliases for imports, and other solutions did cause aliases to stop getting suggested.

Comment: Removing baseUrl might not be a good solution, because you might want to keep it for other imports. Unless you want to disable all absolute imports.

Answer (score 8):

I landed here from Google and had the opposite problem. My Visual Studio Code instance always imported the relative path even though it was from a different [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) package.

It turns out that I simply forgot to add the package that it was wrongly importing to my consuming package’s `package.json` file.

Now, everything works as expected.

Comment: Similarly, using NX and tsconfig paths, we fixed that by using "project-relative" as the importModuleSpecifier. Using just relative changed the other project's import to relative as well which is of course not what we wanted. "project-relative" works great though.

Answer (score 4):

You might need a combination of `baseUrl` and `paths`.

###### tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "holograph/src/*": ["src/*"]
    },
  }
```

###### VSCode settings

```
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative" // or "shortest"
```

My folders are like this. When I am in `apps/app`, I can auto-import in VSCode from packages with `from 'holograph/src/ui/...'`. But when I am in `packages/holograph` ui components, for a reason I haven't yet discovered, it auto-imports from `src/ui`, which gives a build error. I had to manually import from the package path `hologrpah/src/ui`. Doing the above paths import re-map fixed VSCode auto-imports.

```
node_modules
apps (next.js applications)
 ├── app
 |   └── pages
 ├── operator
 ├── storybook
packages (shared components & libraries)
 ├── holograph
 |   └── src
 |       └── ui
 ├── tsconfig
 ├── eslint-config-holograph
...
```

---

PS: This worked too, but I am not sure how valid this is. Basically setting the baseUrl one folder up. ‍♂️

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../",
    },
  }
```

Comment: Finally!!! This VSCode settings It does not appear anywhere!

Comment: @MrEduar Duuuuude, hell yeah!! I spent like a month manually fixing all imports, occasionally searching for a solution that didn't exist. Then I got fed up and spent two days figuring this out. Such a relief.