# Nestjs e2e testing | Cannot found module in controller

Tags: javascript, jestjs, nestjs

I had started studying testing in nestjs and I'm stuck. I'm using e2e tests.

When I try to run the test, I get an error message:

```
 FAIL  test/category.e2e-spec.ts
 ● Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module 'src/auth/jwt-auth-unprotected.guard' from '../src/category/category.controller.ts'

Require stack:
  C:/Users/losak/OneDrive/Desktop/back.zumzak/src/category/category.controller.ts
  C:/Users/losak/OneDrive/Desktop/back.zumzak/src/category/category.module.ts
  category.e2e-spec.ts

  13 | } from '@nestjs/common';
  14 | import { Request } from 'express';
> 15 | import { JwtAuthUnprotectedGuard } from 'src/auth/jwt-auth-unprotected.guard';
     | ^
  16 | import { JwtAuthGuard } from 'src/auth/jwt-auth.guard';
  17 | import { CategoryService } from './category.service';
  18 | import { CreateCategoryDto } from './dto/create-category.dto';

  at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (../node_modules/.pnpm/jest-resolve@28.1.3/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:491:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (../src/category/category.controller.ts:15:1)
```

Here's my spec code (category.e2e-spec.ts):

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { CategoryModule } from '../src/category/category.module';
import * as request from 'supertest';

describe('CategoryController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [CategoryModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('/ (GET)', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/category')
      .expect(200)
  });
});
```

Here's my module (category.module.ts):

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CategoryController } from './category.controller';
import { ShopModule } from 'src/shop/shop.module';
import { FileService } from 'src/file/file.service';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma.service';
import { CategoryService } from './category.service';

@Module({
  imports: [ShopModule],
  controllers: [CategoryController],
  providers: [CategoryService, PrismaService, FileService],
})
export class CategoryModule {}
```

And here's my controller (category.controller.ts) import:

```
import { Request } from 'express';
import { JwtAuthUnprotectedGuard } from 'src/auth/jwt-auth-unprotected.guard';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from 'src/auth/jwt-auth.guard';
import { CategoryService } from './category.service';
import { CreateCategoryDto } from './dto/create-category.dto';
import { ParamsCategoryDto } from './dto/params-category.dto';
import { ParamsSearchDto } from './dto/params-search.dto';
import { UpdateCategoryDto } from './dto/update-category.dto';
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865678/nestjs-test-suite-failed-to-run-cannot-find-module-src-article-article-entity) is explained.

In the overview **don't use absolute path**, those are lost when compiling, use **relative path instead**.

If using VSCode set the imports to relative in the typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier setting, it is by default shortest.