# Storybook Can't Find Components in React, Next.JS, Typescript Project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, storybook

I have storybook setup with my next.js, typescript and react project. The project renders fine but storybook breaks and give me the me error: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'components/atoms' in...." It seems like the path to components is causing it to break:

```
import { Element } from 'components/atoms';
```

but the following works:

```
import { Element } from '../../atoms
```

I have a tsconfig.json file with the following:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
...
```

I tried some of the suggestions online but none seems to resolve the path issue. I created a webpack.config.js in my .storybook folder with the following, but still get errors.

```
module.exports = {
 ...
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules']
  }
};
```

I would like to not use the `../../` when calling files and just be able to use the `./components` structure.

Comment: What is your structure repo?

Comment: Updated the question with the structure of the repo

Comment: You seemingly have to add `.storybook/main.js` to configure you webpack by adding an `alias` to your `./src/components`

Comment: I have a .storybook/main.js file it has configs for stories and addons. I would add an alias here to my `./src/components' to this file? Would I still need the webpack.config.js in this case?

Comment: Here is the way you add your alias to https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack#extending-storybooks-webpack-config. You don’t need your webpack.config.js

Comment: Thank you, that worked by adding the webpackFinal code as suggested by them to my main.js and adding `path.resolve('./src/')` to the config they provided.

Answer (score 17):

Spent some time fighting with Storybook )

Here is my .storybook/main.js version, that finally worked:

```html
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'));

    return config;
  },

  stories: [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For someone who is still looking for a solution, try adding the below inside your webpackFinal before returning config. It is because storybook isn't configured to access files using absolute paths.

```
config.resolve.modules = [...(config.resolve.modules || []), path.resolve('./')]
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers above worked for my NPM workspace project.

What was causing the issue for me was vscode started using imports from src like this:

```
import { MyComponent } from "src/components/Mycomponent";
```

but what I found works with storybook is relative imports like this

```
import { MyComponent } from "../components/Mycomponent";
```

You can make vscode use relative imports by default by setting the below [(see this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53137571)

```
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have setup Storybook with Typescript (I'm also using NextJs but I think that's irrelevant here), the webpack alias change didnt work for me.

I had this error for anything insight my components directry. eg
`@/components/IconType`

I was missing this from the tsconfig.json, which makes sense that Storybook didn't understand the base directory for where to look:

`"baseUrl": ".",`

Hope that helps others

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue resolving aliases

Error: Can't resolve '@foo/bar'

In root > .storybook/main.js I added the property config.resolve.alias

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../libs/feature/src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      '@foo/bar': path.resolve(__dirname, '../libs/bar/src/'),
    };

    return config;
  },
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need is path aliases.
If you're working on a typescript project, you can declare aliases that map to a certain absolute path in your application using `tsconfig.json paths compiler option`:

```json
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
  "components/*": ["components/*"],
  "@/common/*": ["common/*"],
 }
```

- Official link => [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths)
- Here you have a good explanation about this typescript feature.
  [Path aliases with TypeScript in Node.js](https://dev.to/larswaechter/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353)

Be aware that is not always that easy because in production your build toolchain will have to translate them to the correct paths as tsc doesn’t do it.
Fortunately nexjts has added this feature recently => https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases