# How to use intellisense with at symbol ('@') in Vite?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, vite

Using a Vite app I can include this in my vite.config.js:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
},
```

which allows me to use the '@' symbol (at character) for path names. This lets me have imports that look like this:

```
import Home from "@/pages/Home.vue";
```

As opposed to this:

```
import Home from "../../../pages/Home.vue";
```

The problem is that intellisense won't show up in any meaningful way when using the '@' path but it will when I use the '..' path. How do I enable path intellisense starting with '@'

Pictures to clarify what I mean by "intellisense won't show up in any meaningful way when using the '@' path":
[Using '..' path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BUTf.png)

[Using '@' path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb2MX.png)

Answer (score 26):

You also need to tell vscode with `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json` file, for example:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es6",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I have it like this

    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["resources/js/*"]
        }
    },

Comment: @MrEduar make sure your `jsconfig.json` and `resources` folder are in a same directory, then it should work.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same directory but it still did not work. I ended up getting the correct answer from another question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432191/auto-import-in-visual-studio-code-only-offering-absolute-path-with-lerna-subpack/77306167

Answer (score 0):

You must add jsconfig.json file in root your project with paths parameter value:

```
"paths": {
  "@/*": [
    "./src/*"
  ]
},
```

[jsconfig.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80xr0.png)

[structure of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHovv.png)